# Flutter build results with error system cannot find the file specified

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

**UPDATE:**
This below issue resolved after following the migration document, must have missed the >flutter pub get

New to flutter, migrating from 2.7 to 3, for which I have created a new app in Flutter 3 and then copied all the files under /lib folder to the newly created app /lib folder and also I have included all the dependencies that are in pubspec, then I executed >flutter upgrade to upgrade all dependencies taken from 2.7 pubspec to the latest version and then executed >flutter run which is giving below error, I can see the file exists under AppData folder, but still gives below error, please help me understand. Also I tried >flutter clean >flutter cache repair >flutter packages get none of then able to fix the issue.

> lib/view/screens/auth/sign_in_screen.dart:5:8: Error: Error when
> reading
> '/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/country_code_picker-3.0.0/lib/country_code.dart':
> The system cannot find the file specified. import
> 'package:country_code_picker/country_code.dart';

Comment: Can you show me your pubspec.yaml file?